# Why I am unable to run to the Jupyter Notebook in DataSpell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jetbrains-ide, dataspell

I am trying to use the JetBrains DataSpell to run the Jupyter Notebook but I am getting this error:

> Run Error: localhost:8888 failed to respond

[image]

When I click run, Jupyter server start and it says connected (server run fine in the browser when I open the URL) but there is no output for the script. All `*.py` files run just fine. I don't know what I am doing wrong it's my first time using the IDE like this.

I am trying to run Jupyter notebook file on DataSpell but I am getting errors. I tried to put URL manually and created different environments.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.